# retrieve specific records delimited in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following table

```
SNo Data
1 |AA|B|C|D|E|
2 |AB|B|C|D|
3 |AA|C|
4 |AA|
5 |AA|AB|AC|C|
6 |AB|B|C|
```

data is delimited by "|". I understand that the table is denormalized but I cannot change the schema.

The user will give one more more inputs. For example if the user gives input as AA  and C I have to retrieve only those rows where only AA and C occurs and not other rows
In this case my output will be

```
SNo Data
3 |AA|C|
```

The query that I have tried 
`Select * from table1 where data like %AA%C%` will retrieve rows 1,2,3,5,6

Thanks

Comment: What's your question or issue?  If you are trying to construct your query, which programming language is making the MySQL request?

Comment: consider using regular expressions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: You want records that contain *only* AA and C?

Comment: @showdev yes.. records where only AA and C occurs.. AA and C are user inputs.. Can be anything else too

Comment: Are the delimited fields always in sorted (alphabetical) order?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Not necessary

Comment: @Barranka Didn't know I could use regex in sql too..

Comment: Can it match CC|A or it has to be in order?

Comment: @Mihai There isn't any CC in the data.. If you meant |C|AA|, its fine..

Comment: Any limit to the number of | delimiters?More than 5?

Comment: "*I cannot change the schema*" - I'd go back and challenge the premise upon which this statement is made.  This schema is *so bad*, *so difficult to use*, *so unscaleable* and *so contrary to relational principles* that you may as well dump your RDBMS and work from flat files.  Whomever is "requiring" you to keep the existing schema obviously doesn't know what they are talking about, and needs an extremely hard whack with a clue stick post-haste before they do any more damage.

Comment: @Mihai There is no limit to number of delimiters.. Can be any number..

Comment: @eggyal I agree buddy. But I only have select privileges.

Comment: Why did I get down voted? Down voter.. would you mind elaborating the reasons for downvote?

Comment: @Ank: Then you need to talk, persuasively, with someone who can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wildcards, but you have to separate the expressions like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE data LIKE '%|AA|%' AND data LIKE '%|C|%'
```

This gets you all the records that contain both `|AA|` and `|C|`. However, to limit to rows that match only both:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE data LIKE '%|AA|%' AND data LIKE '%|C|%'
AND LENGTH(data) = 6
```

If you have just two, you may as well key them in and actually use an index on the `data` column though:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE data = '|AA|C|' OR data = '|C|AA|'
```

Which on older versions of MySQL can be optimized to:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE data = '|AA|C|'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE data = '|C|AA|'
```

Alternatively, you could use a regular expression, which would not utilize an index.

Comment: The search columns might not necessary be AA and C. User might give C and D. In that case lenght(data) = 6 might not work.

Comment: @Ank, right, `6` would be calculated. Something like `LENGTH('|AA|') + LENGTH('|C|') - (2 - 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that within a record:

- "blank" values are not to be ignored—i.e. `|AA||C|` is not the same as `|AA|C|`; and
- none of the values are repeated—i.e. `|AA|C|AA|` will never occur.

Then you can perform pattern matches and test the total value length:

```
SELECT SNo
FROM   my_table
WHERE  data LIKE CONCAT('%|', 'AA', '|%')
   AND data LIKE CONCAT('%|', 'C' , '|%')
   AND CHAR_LENGTH(data) = 1 + CHAR_LENGTH('AA')
                         + 1 + CHAR_LENGTH('C' )
                         + 1
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd7a9/4/0).

Answer (score 0):

A little idea using regular expressions:

```
select * from table1 where data regexp '(\\|AA\\|)+.*(\\|C\\|)+';
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, what you are asking is "get the rows which matches input with delimiter".

So if input is "AA" and "c" then get rows where `Data` column will have result exactly like
`|AA|C|`

You can probably do like

```
select * from table1 where data = select concat('|',concat_ws('|','AA','C'),'|')
```

Comment: What if `data` was stored as `|C|AA|`?

Comment: Going purely by the sample data alone, one could simply do `SELECT 3 AS SNo, '|AA|C|' AS Data`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$whereClause = array();
foreach( $input AS $search ){
  $whereClause[] = sprintf("data REGEXP '|?%s|?'", $search);
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $whereClause);
```

### Regular Expression Explained

This is the regular expression `'|%s|'` .